# Can a bounded number sequence be strictly ascending?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The title says it. Can a bounded number sequence be strictly ascending / descending?

I have a problem that tells me the sequence of fractional parts $(\{nx\})_{n\geq 1}$ (where $x$ is given) is ascending. But I know that the sequence is bounded $[0,1)$. Thus, shouldn’t the sequence stop ascending at a point? Please show me a proof or something.

Comment: A series deals with summation. A sequence deals with individual elements.

Comment: You've received two examples of a bounded sequence that is strictly increasing.  But I'm questioning your premise.  For a fixed $x$, the sequence $(\{nx\})_{n\ge1}$ is never strictly increasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Though the mathematic series is "In mathematics, a series is, roughly speaking, a description of the operation of adding infinitely many quantities,"

So basically the sequence of the partial sums of e.g. a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)
with rate `r`: `0<r<1` will be an ever increasing, bounded, number. Copy pasting wikipedia:

[image]

This is also relates to [Zeno's Paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes).

Comment: +1 for Zeno's paradox

Answer (score 21):

> Can a bounded number sequence be strictly ascending?

Sure it can.

**Hint**

$0.9 \;,\; 0.99  \;,\;  0.999  \;,\; \ldots$

Answer (score 16):

I presume you mean sequence, not series.  For example, the sequence $1 - 1/n$ is bounded and strictly increasing.